# How to display a picture in android? my first android app

Tags: android, image

I was following a tutorial and everything was going fine until I tried adding a picture.

Before I post the code this is what I'm using:

eclipse with android add-on
build target: 2.2 api 8
avd target: 2.2 api 8

In the tutorial I was told to make my own drawable folder in res so I did and have 3 .pngs in the folder. Yes I tried using the drawable-hdpi folder instead but still get this error:

"Sorry the application blah blah has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutVert"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="125dp"
android:background="@layout/activity_postage_calculator"
android:gravity="center|left|top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
tools:context=".PostageCalculator" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="@string/package_type"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutHoriz1"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/letter" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutHoriz2"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/letter"
        android:src="@drawable/letter" />
      </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Some logcat stuff:

```
01-14 23:27:04.174: D/AndroidRuntime(268): Shutting down VM
01-14 23:27:04.205: W/dalvikvm(268): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.pitt.cs1635.tdo7.prog1/edu.pitt.cs1635.tdo7.prog1.PostageCalculator}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at edu.pitt.cs1635.tdo7.prog1.PostageCalculator.onCreate(PostageCalculator.java:12)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  ... 11 more
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:115)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  ... 21 more
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/activity_postage_calculator.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f030000
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1834)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:285)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  ... 25 more
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag LinearLayout
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:784)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
01-14 23:27:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(268):  ... 29 more
```

I'm new to this so anything you guys can give me would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Huh, should there be one more LinearLayout closing tag? Or is that not the full xml?

Comment: In your topmost LinearLayout, I don't think the line android:background="@layout/activity_postage_calculator" is correct. I think this should be "@drawable/activity_postage_calculator"

Comment: rawat you were right (mostly). I just deleted that line since I don't have a background image. I'm guessing eclipse just automatically generated that line. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception states:  *Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag LinearLayout*.

Did you put the layout file (the XML you posted) in the res/drawable directory?  If so, try moving it to the res/layout directory.

Comment: hmm no I have the activity.xml in the res/layout directory

Comment: See the 2 comments above from Kgrover and Swathi Rawat.  Both look promising.  Also, I wonder if the XML parser is upset about the lack of <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> in the document.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the resource is not found.

Check that the name of the file is the same with the one that you call on the XML. And make sure that the name of the file is in all lower case.